# Force Software Keyboard in iOS Simulator for XCUITest

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcuitest, uitest

I am using XCUITest to test UI behaviour when the keyboard is present - for example, if content properly moves up when the keyboard appears.

For some reason, the iOS simulator insists on regularly just disabling the software keyboard. Sometimes while the simulator is restarted, but sometimes even just when switching textfields in the middle of a test.

Is there a way to always force the software keyboard in the simulator? e.g. a command line argument or a property on XCUIDevice? I am running these tests on a CI, so manually enabling the software keyboard in the simulator is not an option.

Answer (score 16):

I added a prescript in Xcode. It writes defaults ConnectHardwareKeyboard NO to ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist file AND quits the Simulator. Quitting simulator is important because when the tests relaunch the simulator, only then it takes into account the defaults value we wrote.

[image]

```
killall Simulator
defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator ConnectHardwareKeyboard -bool false
```

Comment: killall Simulator
defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator ConnectHardwareKeyboard -bool false

Comment: Please someone approve the answer update to include the script.

Comment: This wont work with Xcode project with Multiple Testplans (esp when one is Unit Testplan and another is UITestplan)

Comment: In Xcode 14.3.1, I found when Simulator was started, it will auto-set `ConnectHardwareKeyboard = true` under your booted simulator's DevicePreference. This will override the settings in Pre-actions or script.

Answer (score 5):

```
external_kb_connected=false

osascript -e 'quit app "Simulator"'

SIMUS_KEYBOARD=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :DevicePreferences" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist | perl -lne 'print $1 if /^    (\S*) =/')

echo "$SIMUS_KEYBOARD" | while read -r a; do /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :DevicePreferences:$a:ConnectHardwareKeyboard $external_kb_connected" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist || /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c  "Add :DevicePreferences:$a:ConnectHardwareKeyboard bool $external_kb_connected" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist; done
```

Running the above script in a "Build phase" of the test target will disable the external keyboard in all simulators.

Comment: It sure would be nice if Apple had a default to allow the hardware keyboard to be connected AND set the keyboard to be displayed.  : /

Comment: It might also be good to copy the current settings file in this script and add it to a Before Run script and have an After Run script to restore it.  If I have time, I'll add it in another reply.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue and this worked for me:

> (Click on Simulator) > Hardware > Keyboard
>
> then uncheck "Connect Hardware Keyboard"

Comment: Thanks for the response. I should have mentioned that the tests are run on a CI, so any manual fix for this is unfortunately not possible. Still voted the answer up since it might help somebody who is having this issue on their local machine.

Comment: I think it is implied in the question that the test is automated - thus, no manual clicking on the Simulator menu to enable software keyboard.